# Grant Permission to Moderators to Mark Answer

Tags: discussion

Too many questions exists that have already a very close and correct answer.
I am pretty sure you have answered questions that you know it is 100% correct. However the OP (original poster) neglects the action of marking as answer. This ignorance can have many reasons:

1. The OP really didn't find an appropriate answer
2. Answers are close but not the real answer
3. The OP has not read the [tour page](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and doesn't know how this site functions.
4. There is (or are) high voted answers, the OP knows the rules (tour) but declines to mark as answer because of ignorance. Although it's been a long time since the creation of the question.

So generally this situation roots in the answers (no correct answer) or the OP. We cannot do anything with a non-answered question, but I think those that are related to OP should be handled appropriatelly. My suggestion is to give the moderators this persmission of marking these types of question as answered. Some criteria can be defined (e.g. the answer is old enough and up-voted enough)

I found a similiar post that wants to [Encourage accepting answers on GIS Stack Exchange?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58/encourage-accepting-answers-on-gis-exchange)

Some nice ideas were introduced there

- % accepted answer (matt wilkie)
- Shunning (Kirk)
- Option presented to the Questioner (Devdatta)

Finding all of these useful, none has been incorporated into stackexchange so far.

Any thought?

Answer (score 6):

To get this feature request implemented would require you to take this to Meta Stack Exchange rather than Meta GIS SE because it would need to be implemented at a level above our site.

However, I would not recommend doing that because similar earlier feature requests have not been well received.  [Moderators accepting answers on user's behalf after a certain time period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18312/moderators-accepting-answers-on-users-behalf-after-a-certain-time-period) seems to be the duplicate that the others point back to there, but if you click this [search link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=moderator+accept+answer+%5Bfeature-request%5D) I think you will see that its reception in many forms has not been good.

My interpretation of those posts, and my own assessment of the situation, is that the option for a question asker to accept an answer to their question should be left squarely in their hands.  An Accept does not and is not intended to "close" or indicate the "correct" answer to a question, it merely indicates the answer that the asker alone thought was the most useful to them, and gives them 15 points to use as a reward to that answerer.

As a moderator, I would not want to be able to exercise a users Accept vote, even if they did not want to use it themselves, and even if they wanted me to.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I think introducing some metrics to score people based on their acceptance rate is a nice feature. Then the users will try to improve this score and to review their past questions and tidy things up.

Comment: @FaridCher, not sure if you are aware but in the earlies of StackExchange, there used to be an '[accept rate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work?rq=1)' stat in every user profile. Not only is the idea today not well received by the SE community, but also it was once removed from the system after showing to cause more harm than good. [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work?rq=1) is one example, but there are many others.

Comment: @AndreSilva , it's weird, how can such a wonderful feature cause harm!? I have had many situations that the OP didn't know what "mark as answer" means, so by guiding him/her, he/she marked the answer. what is the motivation of users helping others solve their problems? Don't tell me it is for the sake of God or to build a wonderful world!

Comment: @FaridCher, if you follow the links I provided in my previous comment and the related questions linking to them you will see the arguments. I won't say users helping users is to build a wonderful world, indeed, reputation, votes, answer accepted are cool and motivating features of this site. However, there are other reasons for users helping users besides that ones (some examples, [here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/974/what-motivates-people-to-answer-questions)). Continues..

Comment: Unfortunately having an answer accepted it is influenced by many things other than the quality of an answer (as you listed in #3 and #4). Best solution I found so far to deal with this and help improving the site is focusing on things we have the control, i.e., answering the best as possible, voting, editing questions I answer for readability, editing other questions, reviewing, etc. Sometimes I see that an OP commented some answer which solved his/her problem. In such cases I leave a comment incentivising the accept (it helps with #3). (@FaridCher)

Comment: @AndreSilva, very nice link about motivations, thanks. I will continue with the existing features of the site but I still persist that some metrics should become available to enumerate users acceptance rate.

Answer (score 1):

If this cannot be implemented at the Meta GIS SE; I suggest to encourage/remind the OP to mark it as correct answer. Alternatively, it would be good to have a standard feedback that we could add if we find such answers.

For example: "If you find this answer correct and useful, please mark it as the correct answer"

In addition, perhaps new users do not know how to mark the answers as accepted since it is a greyed-out tick which took me a while to understand its purpose and people were asking me to mark the answer as correct until I figured it out.

[image]